# Living intermediate species?

Tags: phylogenetics, speciation, species, hybridization

Hypothetical question regarding three animals 'species' {A, B, C}.

Are there any examples in nature where {A and B} *cannot* regularly produce viable offspring, however {A and C} and {B and C} *can* regularly produce viable offspring.

I imagine that such a situation could arise if {A, B, C} have a common ancestor, but {A and B} are sufficiently different from each other, but not from C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hybridization situation you describe could be found in [ring species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species), and is partially related to this concept.
For instance, the three species A, B and C could have partially overlapping distributions, such as:

[image]

In such a situation (assuming that the relative distributions have been stable over evolutionary time), A and C might be able to produce offspring, as well as B and C, while A and B might **not** produce viable offspring if they would meet.

Here is a picture from the wikipedia page for a similar situation, showing interbreeding between seven gull species in the genus *Larus*:

[image]

However, I also know that the ring species concept has been challanged, mainly by the fact that there are very few good empirical examples of ring species. See for instance the nice blog post "[*There are no ring species*](https://whyevolutionistrue.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/there-are-no-ring-species/)" by Jerry Coyne, which may also include a couple of examples of species groups that are relevant to your question.

Also, the hybridization patterns that you describe can be caused by other processes, for instance specific reproductive barriers between groups of species (molecular or behavioural). My answer is therefore merely mentioning one possible explanation for the hybridization patterns you ask for, but there are many other processes to consider.

Comment: I don't know what the molecular mechanism behind this phenomenon is but one possibility is presence of a set of lethal mutations that can be compensated in certain crosses.

Comment: I don't know either, and it will depend on particular species pairs. My last point is mainly that there exists other examples of the type of hybridization patterns that the OP describes, that doesn't involve ring species. There are probably examples of sympatric species where A+C and B+C can produce viable offspring, but not A+B, depending on specific features of their reproductive barriers.

Comment: Re Jerry Coyne's blog post -- What is it about Darwinian Theory that engenders so many dead-end conjectures and false pedagogical stories?

Comment: @user23715 Maybe that a naive version of evolution is *higher fitness* + *selection* -> *perfect adaptation*, which easily can lead to *pattern-based apparent adaptation* (or other "outcome" assumed to be the result of evolution) -> *inference assuming selective forces*

Comment: Maybe it's the underlying theory though and not just a naive understanding of it? See the recent "news" about Great Ape Evolution (*Pliobates cataloniae*). --- If the underlying theory is sound wouldn't it be driving field and lab work that supports itself instead of "turning it on it's head" as happens so often? --- The Standard Model in particle physics is known to be incomplete yet has truly underpinned the associated research. --- NDE and biology? Meh, not so much.

Comment: @user23715 Are you saying that the modern account of evolution has often been turned on its head? If so, when? What about the finding of *Pliobates cataloniae* do you find problematic (I've only seen a couple of headlines so far)?

Comment: The Mods will probably move this to chat but, in a nutshell: What is it about NDE that produces ideas like Ring Species or a proposed "tree" for the evolution of the Great Apes, and yet when field work is done in support of the idea, instead of reinforcing it, the theoretical concept gets "turned on its head"? --- Contrast this with Plate Tectonics, a theory that fruitfully guides field work in geology --- Or the aforementioned Standard Model in physics. These latter two have proven themselves time and again. NDE not so much. There is seemingly nothing about NDE that drives fruitful research.

Comment: @user23715 Exactly what are you referring to with "NDE" (not familiar with the acronym)?

Comment: Neo-Darwinian Evolution.

Comment: @user23715 If you truly believe that "*There is seemingly nothing about NDE that drives fruitful research.*" you must be either ignorant about what is going on in evolutionary research or ideologically blinded. I don't think we will get further in this comment-field discussion though.

Comment: "Ring Species" was an idea birthed by NDE thinking. "Ring Species" do **not** exist... or *maybe* one example exists. What's wrong with NDE that it promotes thinking like this? --- Compare with the fruitfulness of the Standard Model in physics or Plate Tectonics in Geology. It just seems odd to me that the fundamental theory in Biology doesn't actually produce anything worthwhile. Advances in Population Genetics, Molecular Biology, etc. have all taken huge leaps irrespective of any potential underlying link to NDE. --- Name any recent (50 yrs +-) advance in Biology needs NDE to be understood.

Answer (score 4):

The term that describes this phenomenon is 'clinal speciation', and the easiest examples to point to are all '[ring species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species)'.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species) mentions four ring species examples. Three are avian examples ([*Larus* gulls](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1474-919X.1967.tb04005.x/pdf), [Song Sparrows](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=3760384&fileId=S1477200008002867), and [Greenish Warblers](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v511/n7507/full/nature13285.html)), and one is a plant example (*[Euphorbia tithymaloides](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/early/2012/06/11/rspb.2012.0498)*).

The classification of the *Larus* gull complex as a ring species is contested. Liebers et al ([2004](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1691675/)) argue that the isolation-by-distance model, with genetic contact at all near points of the species' range, is not well-supported by genetic analyses for this species, and that the species' genetic structure is better explained by a series of 'splitting' events associated with long-distance colonisation followed by genetic isolation of the new colony.